# Telling when iCloud has no more pending changes for Core Data update

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, icloud

The `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`(I hope you're using a wide screen...) notification is received after updated records are imported from iCloud. But is there a way to tell that there are no more updates pending?

I need this mainly to detect the end of the initial update when a new store is added to iCloud, so that I can merge existing data safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you have no means to tell whether there are any changes pending/not pending from the iCloud.